# What is Wrong with my Physics Equations in this Matplotlib Graph of Object Trajectories?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot object trajectories in python using matplotlib. I have made the x velocity constant and the y velocity is affected by gravity. I have used the equations Vx = Vo(cos(ϴ)) and Vy = Vo(sin(ϴ)) to find the initial X and Y velocities. I am using a for loop to find each point the projectile would be at for every tenth of a second. The problem is that my equations must be incorrect somewhere because the graph is inaccurate. Here is my code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

def plot():
    Position = [0,0] #Physical X and Y coordinates
    BulletVelocity = 961 #m/s
    Gravity = 9.8 #m/s^2
    GraphList = [[],[]] # PlottedX and Y coodinates
    frametime = 0.1  #Time between iterations in the for loop
    theta = 44       #Angle at which projectile is launched
    XVelocity = BulletVelocity * math.cos(theta) #initial X velocity
    YVelocity = BulletVelocity * math.sin(theta) #initial Y velocity
    time = 0
    while Position[1] >= -1: #check for if the projetile has hit the ground
        GraphList[0].append(Position[0])
        GraphList[1].append(Position[1])
        YVelocity = YVelocity - Gravity * time #Y Velocity changes due to gravity
        Position[1] = YVelocity * time
        Position[0] = XVelocity * time
        time += frametime #time passes

    plt.xlim(0,2000)
    plt.ylim(0,2000)
    plt.plot(GraphList[0],GraphList[1],'r') #Graph the list of points
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()

plot() #call the plot() function
```

Here is my Graph

I don't have enough reputation points to post images so you will have to view it [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t4uVYr32K2ZiX0gci2y0faZ5nIMTL4UD/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `math.sin` and `math.cos` expect radians, not degrees. You can convert degrees to radians by multiplying them by pi/180. If you change the definition of `theta` to:

```
theta = (math.pi/180)*44
```

Then your code seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

The radians was the main issue, but I'd also like to add this:

```
    # s = vt - 0.5 * (a * t**2)
    Position[1] = YVelocity * time - 0.5 * (-Gravity * time ** 2)
```

You were just missing the acceleration part of calculating the displacement. It's fine for x though since acceleration is 0 i.e.

```
Position[0] = XVelocity * time - (0)
```

Comment: Ah! Thankyou for putting up with my feeble yet growing knowledge of physics